# How to seek different employment while still on the job

Tags: job-change, employer-relations, employer

i'd like to move up (and out) from my current role and into a more technology-centric company.  What is the best way to achieve this given that (i assume) the vast majority of interviews and employer-prospective employer contacts happen during working hours.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18626/29909

Comment: You're going to have to take PTO

Comment: @LawrenceAiello Roger that.  Do you think I'd have adequate time to request off as an interview is requested?  Are employers generally flexible with the interview schedule.  I was previously unemployed when I landed this current session.

Comment: see also: [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/168)