# Timings for interview

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I have a minimum wage job which is going to start this coming monday, that'll be the first day of job.  And on the same day I have a video interview scheduled for a job that is in my field of expertise.

I'm little deep in debts and have been unemployed for a while. How should I manage my situation?

I originally arranged the video conference for an earlier date but the employer cancelled it. I don't want to change the timings for the  video conference, nor do I want to make another employer feel bad or give him a wrong impression on the 1st day.

Comment: I don't understand if they cancelled the interview, why you'd pick a conflicting time?  Is it that hard to just reschedule with them?

Comment: [Relevant](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/how-to-arrange-for-interviews-without-taking-leave)

Comment: I don't know, the rescheduling involved a delay of another week or more, a week had already passed since earlier cancellation, so what if they hire someone else in between.. just wanted to go through this asap..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have explained to your low wage employer that you are filling in while you hunt for a longer term option then they may well be prepared to let you take the interview - while working around it. Discuss it with them ASAP.

If you haven't explained your situation fully to your low wage employer then you should really stick to agreement & re-schedule the interview at a time convenient to all three parties - you, current employer, potential employer.

If on your first day your **first conversation with your new boss is along the lines of 'oh, forgot to mention it but I need a couple of hours this afternoon because I want a job somewhere else' it won't go well** if this is a new development. Your employer may well give you all the time you need to get another job.

Comment: did that amelvin.. i honestly and briefly told him that a 30 mins break is required for a call.. he asked me to start one hour after the call is over. He hitched a little bit but it was ok with him.

Comment: hope it all works out!

Answer (score 6):

Simply reschedule the video interview for a date that is more convenient for you.

Now that you have a job (as low paid as it is), you need to work your job hunting around that.  Employers/agencies are usually understanding that people have jobs and can't really drop everything and take an interview on a whim.

Comment: +1 interviewing for a different job on the first day at a new job is bad practice!